# Reagraph library - Connecting clusters instead of nodes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am working with the reagraph library. I have a use-case where I need to connect the clusters of nodes. Through this library, it is possible to create [clusters](https://reagraph.dev/?path=/story/demos-cluster--simple) and it is possible to have [edges between nodes in clusters](https://reagraph.dev/?path=/story/demos-cluster--edges). But I need to create edges between the clusters  themselves. Would that be possible through this library? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

I have tried checking different options available. I haven't received much info about this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.